# :ref: link not giving link

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Inside `addCompanies.rst` I have

```
Add Companies
=============

:ref: _my-reference-label:

adding
-----

ahdlkasdflk
This documentation will help you to add homes.
```

Now I am trying to link the file from another file `change.rst` in the same directory

```
Change company
=============

* How to add new company ? my-reference-label_
```

But the `my-reference-label` which I wanted to be a link is not producing any link.

What might be the problem here? Also what if I want to link the file from another directory file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you use above appears to be a non-sensical confusion of valid link syntax.  You have the syntax for [cross-referencing arbitrary links](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/inline.html#role-ref) incorrect.  This should remedy it and will work between files.

### addCompanies.rst

```
Add Companies
=============

.. _my-reference-label:

adding
------
```

### change.rst

```
Change company
==============

* How to add new company ? :ref:`my-reference-label`
```

Also make sure that the underlines match the length of their text.